# Using Legacy code functions in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-directive

I have a ton of legacy javascript functions(sign up/sign in using parse.com) and wanted to use angularJS for routing and other benefits. Can I use create an angular stack and wrap these functions as angular modules. If possible, how so?

PS: I'm new in AngularJS and connecting parse.com with Angjs is a wreck.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is a JavaScript framework. Any JavaScript functions would of course work. And if you need to, you can create a separate module for your functions and make different services for each function, so that you can inject them in your controllers in the best way.